# How to publish a page to two sites?

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I have a root site and a sub-site. I want to enable the following function -- when the sub-site administrator publishing a page, the administrator could select to publish to the sub-site only or publish to both root site and sub-site.

Any ideas how to implement this? I am not sure whether there is any ready-to-use solution without writing code?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused... is there a sub-site administrator as well as a root site administrator or are they the same person?

Comment: In my situation, they are not. The scenario is, the sub-site administrator may choose some pages (news) and submit to root site (portal) administrator for approval to publish on root site, if approved, on the root site, the news from subsite could be published. If the sub-site administrator wants to publish news on sub-site, the sub-site administrator could feel free to publish -- no need the root site administrator to approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the root and sub-site administrators are the same person, a simple way to do this is by using Manage Content and Structure [as described previously](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/438/how-to-approve-publish-a-couple-of-pages-together-in-sharepoint/439#439).

Browse to the root site and open Manage Content and Structure. Then change the view to "All Draft Documents". You can then then use the drop-down menu on each page and choose the Publish option.

---

**Update after comment:**

As they are not the same person, the short answer is that SharePoint doesn't support this scenario out of the box. I think you would need to write a custom workflow to make this happen.

Comment: I used Manage Content and Structure interface and all draft contains unpublished documents. My question is, I need to publish the document to two locations (publish to both subsite and root site). How to make the draft document to two locations?

Comment: Any updates Alex?

Comment: Can't help much more George, sorry (see my edit). But I would leave this question unanswered as someone might have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is make it directly navigable from pages in the root site (using something that looks and behaves like a menu) you might want to add a boolean field "ShowOnRootSite" to your custom page content type and have a ContentQueryWebPart on the root site that rolls up all pages in your sitecollection where ShowOnRootSite = true.

That way you don't have to maintain content on two pages and worry about keeping content in synch when one of them changes. If one of your goals is that you actually want to have two separate pages that are disconnected from each other then the above trick won't be of much use to you.

Comment: 1. "you might want to add a boolean field "ShowOnRootSite" to your custom page content type" -- I am confused. The page is just a normal web page published in SharePoint publishing portal. What do you mean "custom page content type" (my confusion is, I am not using any custom types, but built-in SharePoint page). 2. How to add the boolean field, through coding or have some way to configure w/o coding?

Comment: You can do it without coding. Create a new content type that derives from the standard publishing page and add a new boolean field to that. I am sure there are many articles out there that will tell you how to do this.

Comment: Hi Jaap, I am new to this area. I tried to find some related documents but failed. Any recommended documents to read?

Comment: Any updates Jaap?

Comment: Sorry - I don't mean to be rude, but please try googling a bit on this one, there's loads of info to be found on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

[nanyang royal Hotel Guangzhou](http://www.nanyangroyalhotel-guangzhou.cn)
[zhaolong Hotel Beijing](http://www.zhaolonghotelbeijing.cn)
[Chong Wen Men Hotel Beijing](http://www.chongwenmenhotelbeijing.cn)
[Tong Mao Hotel Shanghai](http://www.tongmaohotelshanghai.cn)
[white palace hotel Guangzhou](http://www.whitepalacehotelguangzhou.cn)